# отложенная публикация постов wp

Tags: wordpress

Привет всем!
Скриптом добавляю посты в базу wordpress'а, в поле "post_status" пишу значение "future", а в поле "post_date" и "post_date_gmt" - дату публикации. Но при наступлении даты публикации статус поста не меняется на "publish" и соответственно пост не появляется на сайте :(
Подскажите, как быть

код добавления поста:

```
mysql_query ('INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_name`, `post_type`) values ("1", "' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 60) . '", "' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 60 - 3600*3) . '", "text post", "post title", "future", "1", "open", "post-title", "post");');
```

Comment: а если добавить отложенную запись через админку, она публикуется в назначенное время?

Comment: Отвечаю за ТС, поскольку знаком с ситуацией. Да. Более того, если пробежаться по уже добавленным постам и ВРУЧНУЮ прощелкать "обновить", то все добавленные записи изменят свой статус в зависимости от времени публикации: - те, что добавлены прошлым числом, останутся опубликованными
- те, что добавлены будущим числом, станут запланированными и опубликуются в выставленное время.

Comment: Да, через админку всё работает

Comment: опубликуйте в вопросе фрагмент кода, который добавляет отложенные записи, будем разбираться

Comment: Добавил фрагмент кода, который добавляет пост с датой публикации на минуту вперед

Answer (score 1):

При публикации отложенного поста через админку WordPress не только помещает его в базу, но и запускает задачу wp_cron. Ваш код этого не делает.
Используйте для создания поста функции WordPress, например wp_insert_post.